# Squirrel-cage air blower efficiency

Tags: airflow, industrial-engineering

What would be the typical efficiency of a large industrial single-stage squirrel-cage air blower?

For example how many kilograms of ambient air (STP) would be moved per second by such blower which needs 20kW of electric power to turn its impeller (assuming 90% electric motor efficiency, make that 18kW of mechanical power at the impeller).

Answer (score 1):

These are called centrifugal fans and are typically from 60 to 90% efficient.

They are tested and rated by Air Movement and Control Association, AMCA.

They are usually tested under standard air conditions, which is clean, dry air at sea level 21 Celsius with barometric pressure of 29.92inches Mercury ( SCFM). The manufacturers usually have performance charts for different air pressure, temperature, density, etc.

Here is Wikipedia link. [Centrifugal fan Wiki](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centrifugal_fan)